# Def. of lin independence for subsets

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, definition

I use following definition:

> let be $v:\Bbb{N} \to T$ with $T\subseteq V $ and $V $ a $K-$vector space: $$ (v_i)_{i \in \Bbb{N}} \text{ is lin. ind. if } \\ \forall \alpha \in K^\Bbb{N}: \sum_{i \in \Bbb{N}} \alpha_i \, v_i=0 \wedge \exists m \in \Bbb{N}:\forall n>m: \alpha_n=0 \to \forall i \in \Bbb{N}: \alpha_i=0$$

Now I need a definition not for family of vectors but for subsets of $V $ . I thinked $T \subseteq V$ is lin ind if $\forall x\in T: x \notin <T\setminus \{x\}> $ but I have following problem:

> the family of vectors  $((1,2), (1,2)) $ ist not lin ind, but the set $\{(1,2)\} $ ist lin ind...

Are there therefore two definitions of lin ind, one for families and one for sets?!

Comment: You are wrestling with a definition that has almost no English words. Try this definition and see if you can solve: a collection of vectors (vectors could be repeated, so not calling this collection a set)  $v_1,v_2,\ldots, v_n$ is linearly independent if there is  NO way, other than all 0,  to find scalars $a_i$ such that the sum $a_1v_1+a_2v_2+\cdots a_nv_n$ will be zero vector.

Comment: What do you mean with "collection"? Why do you use a finite "collection"? In my question I have a countable subset!!!

Comment: What is a collection? Well here is an  Illustration, instead of a definition: . a  real polynomial of degree $n$ has *only a collection* of $n$ (possibly complex) roots, not always  set of $n$ roots. About infinite sets, in algebra there is no concept of infinite sum, or convergence. So infinite collection of vectors is said to be linearly independent iff every  *finite subcollection* is so.

Comment: @P Van, you are wrestling with definitions that have only English words! Collection is set, family is not set, a family is a function ( https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_family)... a polynomial ist function and see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicity_(mathematics)#Multiplicity_of_a_root_of_a_polynomial and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence#Infinite_dimensions

Comment: @Marios, your definition for sets ist good!!! In addition,  [$(v_i) $ is lin ind $\to$  $\{v_i\} $ ist lin ind] is true, but [$\{v_i\} $ is lin ind $\to$  $(v_i)$ is lin ind] is generally false and you have an example ;) . The question is interesting because for example $<(v_i)>=<\{v_i|i \in \Bbb{N}\}> $ is true!!

Answer (score -1):

By definition singleton  sets are always linearly independent.

Let $\{\alpha \neq 0\}$ be a singleton  set. $a_1 \alpha = 0 \implies a_1 = 0 $.

Now $a_1(1,2) + a_2 (1,2) = (0,0) \implies (a_1 +a_2, 2a_1+2a_2) = (0,0) \implies a_1 = -a_2 $. Thus the family of vectors  $((1,2), (1,2)) $ is not linearly independent.

Comment: What definition for singleton?

Comment: See my edit.... I understand your answer but it is not my question

Comment: @user8795, you use two definitions for linear independence...